# How to terminate user session from Attask (Workfront) using SAML?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, saml-2.0, attask

I have integrated Workfront with my application using SAML2. I am able to login with IDP (ADFS) into my system and I can easily access Workfront with the help of SAML token. No need to pass any credential or visit IDP page if user session exist already in my application.

I am using href link to access Workfront from my application as WF enabled Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) so I can not embed into my application.

Now I want to logout from my application and Workfront as well using global logout which will terminate logged in user session from IDP also. But I am not able call Workfront logout URL for SAML from client side code of my application.

Can anybody help me to terminate user session from Workfront application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above problem by using `https://domain.attask-ondemand.com/logout` this url. Now user is able to log out globally from IDP and SP(WF) as well by hitting the given url from my SP. However this URL is not accessible from outside domain due to CORS, so I opened this link in new iframe. Used below code to logout from WF.

```
    iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = "hiddenWFlogout";
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    iframe.src = 'https://domain.attask-ondemand.com/logout';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Answer (score 0):

To initiate a logout you need to define a logout url in the SSO setup page in workfront. This will usually point to the global logout page used for your SAML. if you are an admin(and have admin exception enabled) or have only allow saml2 authentication un checked in your user profile you will be redirected to the normal workfront login screen.

Comment: Michael, I want to initiate Attask saml logout from my application before logging out my own application.

Comment: You could kill the session by hitting domain.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/logout but if you have an active session open with your IDP you will be logged back in automatically when hitting the workfront link.

Comment: By hitting this URL, logged in user not logout from globally (IDP)  and not even redirected to logout page. It is kind of local logout but user can't see any difference until he clicks on some WF link.